# Запрос по категориям. PHP+SQL

Tags: php, sql

Есть база данных с игроками, тренерами, командами и чемпионатами. Каждая новость должна находится в определенной категории. То есть, захожу на страницу чемпионата, а там новости этого чемпионата. Захожу на страницу игрока - новости связанные с игроком. Как это можно организовать? Ведь новость может содержать несколько категорий - несколько команд или игроков.

Comment: Вам нужна промежуточная таблица, связывающая новости и категории - many-to-many.